# Pointer to overloaded method of template class

Tags: c++

I have template with overloaded method. I'm trying to create pointer to the overloaded method.

```
template<typename T>
class Future {
public:
    const T& get() const;
    bool get(T*, int timeoutMs) const;
};

...

const void*&(Future<void*>::*x)()const = &Future<void*>::get;
```

Compilation fails with this error:

```
no matches converting function 'get' to type 'const void*& (class Future<void*>::*)()const'
candidates are: const T& Future<T>::get() const [with T = void*]
                bool Future<T>::get(T*, int) const [with T = void*]
```

I have tried to typedef `Future<void*>` without any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If T is void* the const should be on the pointer not on the pointed memory:

```
void* const & (Future<void*>::*x)() const = &Future<void*>::get;
```

Comment: Thx, it helped. I got stucked for few hours and solution is so simple ... :).

Comment: I think this is a good example of why writing the `const` in front isn't a good idea: 'const T' isn't the same as 'T const' if you put `void *` in place of T.

Answer (score 0):

Templates themselves have no pointers. A template is a **template**, it tells c++ how to create a class. So

```
template<class T>
class Container {
 public:
  T* element() { return element_; }
  void SetElement(Element *element) { element_ = element; }
  typedef void (*SetElementFunctionPointer)(Element *element);
 private:
  T *element_;
};

typedef Container<int> IntContainer;
```

The code above shows you a Container template, and how you create an integer container (`IntContainer`) by using the Container template. In there I've declared a typedef for a `SetElementFunctionPointer`.